# How to import 3rd party binary library in Android Studio 3.4?

Tags: android-studio, jar, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, .so

Backgroud:

I would like to use a third-party library in Android Studio 3.4. The library includes three files:[see pics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TGpQ.png)

- arm64-v8a/libAnalyticsLib.so
- armeabi-v7a/libAnalyticsLib.so
- StrideAnalyticsLib.jar.

The class files within "StrideAnalyticsLib.jar" show that they seem to be generated by using SWIG.

I've tried two ways to import this library but still cannot

- import StrideAnalyticsLib.*;

  But this doesn't allow to access the classes and shows "cannot
  resolve symbol ...".
- the .so files are with jniLibs

  ~/main/jniLibs/

  ~/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libAnalyticsLib.so

  ~/main/jniLibs/armeabi/libAnalyticsLib.so
- the .so files are within libs; At the same time, i added "sourceSets { main{ jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']}}" in build.gradle;

  ~/libs/

  ~/libs/arm64-v8a/libAnalyticsLib.so

  ~/libs/armeabi/libAnalyticsLib.so

Both attempts are followed by cleaning and rebuilding the project.I'm very new to Android and couldn't get it work. Could anyone please provide help? Great Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I studied the process using SWIG to wrap c/c++ library into the .jar and .so., I realised that the .jar and .so will have same package name so that the .jar can call the .so file.

Because my .jar doesn't work when it's saved in /libs, I instead copied all classes within the .jar and pasted them into the /main folder. Remember to put them outside your package, otherwise the package name of these classes will be changed, which cause my problem. The way of importing .so is correct. Just put the .so files inside /main/jniLibs.